# How to store all the input field value from datatable except for the field which is null?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
    var form = this;
    // Encode a set of form elements from all pages as an array of names and values
    var params = table.$('input').serializeArray();
    // Iterate over all form elements
    $.each(params, function(){
        // If element doesn't exist in DOM
        if(!$.contains(document, form[this.name])){
            // Create a hidden element
            $(form).append(
                $('<input>')
                    .attr('type', 'hidden')
                    .attr('name', this.name)
                    .val(this.value)
            );
        }
    });
});
```

I am using this method to store all input field value from datatable, what if i just want to store only input field with value? Is that possible to do it?
And after that in my controller, i want to loop the data and store in database.

Answer (score 0):

Put condition to check null values and then append
This simpler code will work:

```
if(!varName1 || !varName2){
```

Which will check for empty strings (''), null, undefined, false and the numbers 0 and NaN